# Cannot Send an Email Using SMTP module in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, emails

I'm using [SMTP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module to send an email in Drupal 7. I have tested to send an email through configuration and it works. Unfortunately, when I'm trying to send an email after submitting a form (in my apps). It says successful, but no email has been sent to my mail.

I setup the module based on this article: http://www.symphonythemes.com/drupal-blog/configure-drupal-smtp-gmail

Here's the settings:

```
host: host.mycompany.com
port: 25
secure: no
authentication: no
from: info@company.com
from name: Info Company
testing to: myname@company.com
```

Here is the code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use 

$mail->From = "info@company.com";
$mail->FromName = "Info Company";
$mail->AddAddress("myname@company.com", "My Name");

$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else {
   echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

`if(!$mail->Send())` always return true, but no email has been sent.
The email and host are in one domain, so I don't think there is any permission problem?

Comment: You could use drupal_mail. It could be queuing on the server, check the logs.

Comment: maybe you need to run cron?

Comment: My send mail already working with additional param host and port. But, I thought this module will take the SMTP settings from module configuration?